# Spring Security: get controller class in Preauthorize annotation

Tags: spring, spring-security

Many of the controllers I use in a Spring application extend a common abstract class. The methods are thus declared in the abstract class.
I would like to apply a 'PreAuthorize' condition in the abstract method, but I need to get the name of the actual controller class being invoked to be passed to the EL evaluator.
Is there a way to do so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In abstract class implement BeanNameAware interface.

```
public abstract class MyController implements BeanNameAware{

String beanName; 

   @Override
public void setBeanName(final String beanName) {
    this.beanName = beanName;
}

@Override
public String getBeanName() {
    return beanName;
}
}
```

You will get a hold of actual bean name instead regular proxy. If you need further customization implement BeanFactoryAware. You can than use that getBeanName method in SpEl of your preauthorize

Comment: hi, how to use it in preAuthorize ? could you give me an example ?